# Unable to get Date from mongodb and compare it with current Date

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime

I am unable to get end Date from MongoDB and compare it with the Current date (ISO 8106 FORMAT)
I am making a method in a class where the getter setter properties are self built by the Lombock.jar and hence  I want to use the getter method foe getEndDate() directly.Getting null at getEndDate()

What I am trying is as:

```
  public boolean getComparator() {

    boolean SessionisExpired = false;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");

    Date currDate = new Date();
    dateFormat.format(currDate);

    int compare = (this.getEndDate()).compareTo(currDate);

    if (compare == 1) {

        SessionisExpired = true;
   }
    if(SessionisExpired){
        this.Status = "DONE";
    }
```

Comment: What is the exact problem ? Are you facing problem in fetching date from `mongoDb` or comparing it with current date ? Please provide minimal complete program with exception or problem you are currently facing.

Comment: Actually I am facing problem in getting the data from db..When I will get that date then only I would be able to compare it

Comment: Show us the code where you get endDate from Mongo. You must have a query somewhere in your code.

Comment: I am done guys..You can see the answer that I have written below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a problem to my solution as

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();

    LocalDate endLocalDate = endDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    Period dayDifference = Period.between(localDate, endLocalDate);

    log.info("Local Current Date " + localDate + " End Local Date " + endLocalDate + " and Day Difference is "
            + dayDifference);
```